# Re-render does not occur when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component...

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        register: false
    }

  }
  handleClick(event)
    {
      console.log("link was clicked");
      this.setState({register: true});

    }

    render(){


        return (

            <If condition={ this.state.register }>
                <Then><Register /></Then>
                <Else>{() => 
                    <Index event={this.handleClick} />

                }</Else>
            </If>   
        );  
    }
}

module.exports = App;
```

So my function `handleClick` is called whenever a link is clicked, this changes the state to true. However, the `<IF>` statement does not notice that state changed and so remains the same (only Index remains)

What I want is for `<Register />` to be rendered whenever the link is clicked. So if the link is clicked, the state will change to true, and then the IF statement will catch this change and render the right component.

How can I do this? How can I get the `IF` statement to notice the change in state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what `<Index>` is or what is it doing with `event`. If it just calls the function that is passed as `props.event`, the `handleClick` function is called with the wrong `this` reference and doesn't set the state for the correct component.

If you're using Babel with stage-2 preset or lower, you can use syntax to bind `this`:

```
class App ... {
  ...
  handleClick = (event) => { ... }
  ...
}
```

Yes, it's an arrow function definiton, but directly inside `class`. It will `bind` the correct `this` reference so it can be passed around and it will have proper this reference when called.

Alternatively, you can use `bind` directly when passing the function, as `event={this.handleClick.bind(this)}`. But beware, this creates a new function every time it's called, so it might impact performance if it's called very often. It's advised that you do not use this approach and airbnb's eslint config will mark this as an error. A better approach would be to do one time binding inside the constructor, as `this.handleClick= this.handleClick.bind(this)`.

If you wish to know more, [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56#.bkrjrpa1k) covers 2 more ways to bind and explains all 5 options.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by following code,

```
   return (
      { this.state.register ? <Register /> : <Index event={this.handleClick.bind(this)} /> }
    );
```